# Error: "This site can’t be reached" after change domain GCP + openLiteSpeed

Tags: wordpress, google-cloud-platform, openlitespeed

Hello 
First of all I want to mentioned that I'm using **Google cloud platform VM instance, openLiteSpeed + wordpress site.** 
I'm on fly more than a year with some domain and everything works well.
Today I bought a new domain and set it to my website and from this moment I can't enter to my site even if I'm using the External IP of my instance.
For now I deleted all my records in DNS section to try to handle this problem and still it does not work.
I also changed the virtual mapping on Listener section in openLiteSpeed dashboard.
I don't have idea what todo next, I try to solve this more than 5 hours.
Any suggestions how can I solve it ?

Comment: does it work if you curl it on server ssh ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reproduced your scenario in my own project-- I installed “openlitespeed-wordpress” solution.

I realised that this solution doesn't reserve an External IP, so when I stopped the instance and started it again, I wasn’t able to access my WordPress because my original IP was ephemeral, and it changed when I started my VM Instance again.

I solved this problem by modifying 2 fields in the DB, if you have the same issue you can follow the next steps:

1. In the Google Cloud Console, go to the [VM instances](https://console.cloud.google.com/compute/instances?_ga=2.222476955.1653967723.1602508970-638966553.1591892739&_gac=1.148565635.1602166312.EAIaIQobChMI1evg59m36AIVVaqWCh0HFAwSEAAYASAAEgKdEfD_BwE) page to check the new IP for your `openlitespeed-wordpress` Instance.
2. Use your new IP to access to your phpMyAdmin:

```
https://{Your-New-IP}/phpmyadmin/
```

If you don't know your credentials to access to phpMyAdmin you can get this information with the following command using ssh:

```
sudo sed -n 1p /home/ubuntu/.db_password
```

3. Once you have access,  go to wordpress -> wp_options

[image]

4. Then you edit the option name

- siteurl
- home

[image]

After this action **I was able to access my site again** with my New IP.

To avoid this issue in the future you could reserve your IP:

1. In the Cloud Console, go to the [VM instances](https://console.cloud.google.com/compute/instances?_ga=2.9507125.1653967723.1602508970-638966553.1591892739&_gac=1.212034080.1602166312.EAIaIQobChMI1evg59m36AIVVaqWCh0HFAwSEAAYASAAEgKdEfD_BwE) page.
2. Click the name of the instance that you want to assign an external IP to.
   The instance details page displays.
3. From the instance details page, complete the following steps:

a. Click **Edit**.

b. Under **Network interfaces**, click the edit button.

[image]

c. Under **External IP**, select **Static external IP** address to assign to the instance.

[image]

d. Click **Done** and **Save**.

Also I found some [documentation](https://docs.litespeedtech.com/cloud/images/wordpress/#quick-start) that might help you to troubleshoot your issue.

Comment: Thanks you very very much sir!